# Store NSMutableArray of custom objects in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I have a `NSMutableArray` full of a custom object called *CHClipboardObject* I need to save this array to core data so I can use it to populate a `UITableView`. I have looked around on how to do this and this is what I've got so far.

Create class called something like `ArrayData` with one property to hold the `NSMutableArray`

Serialize/conform to `NSCoding` my `CHClipboardObject` which I am not sure how to do.

What do I need to do after these steps?

I need to be able to delete objects in the array from the `UITableView` by swiping, which I have already implemented.

Comment: Make CHClipboardObject as an entity in the model and then show the same in table view using NSFetchResultsController?

Answer (score 1):

1) Set the type to "Transformable"

[image]

2) Implement methods

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
```

on your custom object

3) You are ready to go!

Comment: Would I implement the methods in my `CHClipboardObject` or `ClippingData`?

Comment: You need to implement that methods on Array element (which are the elements of the array)